# How to compare with next row in data frame?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a data frame which looks like this:

```
F_id       type     count   value     
 1           A        0      8
 1           A        2      8 
 1           B        0      2
 1           B        4      2
 1           B        1      2
 1           A        5      8
 2           A        0      3
 2           B        0      9
 1           A        1      3
```

I would like to:

- group consecutive types for each `F_id` then, within each group:
- compare the column `count` with `value` (in the current row? next row? previous row?)
- if `count` in the next row is less than `value` then assign "True"

For instance:

```
F_id      type     count   value    match     
 1         A        0      8         False
           A        2      8         True   //  2 < 8
           A        5      8         True   // 5 < 8
 1         B        0      2         False
           B        4      2         False   
           B        1      2         True  // 1 < 2 
 2         A        0      3         False
           A        1      3         True   // 1 < 3
 2         B        0      9         False
```

I tried the following:

```
n = data.groupby(['F_id','type']).apply(lambda x:
        np.where((x['F_id'] == x['F_id'].shift())&(x['type'] ==
        x['type'].shift())&(x['count'] < x['value']),True,False))

data['match'] = n.reset_index(level = 0, drop=True)
```

but I got:

> ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think pivot tables are what you are looking for

Comment: Why is `match = False` on the first row of each group, even though `value[i] < count[i+1]`? Ah, you must mean *"compare with **previous** row"* not *"compare with next row"*. i.e. `match[i] depends on value[i-1] < count[i]` I tried to edit your question for clarity but could you please edit it yourself?

Comment: `np.where((x['F_id'] == x['F_id']...`  should be totally unnecessary inside a `groupby('F_id')`. You could never have different `F_id`s within that groupby. In fact, you can't even access `F_id` within a `groupby('F_id')`.

Comment: Another problem: in your example, `value` column happens to be constant within every group, but your problem statement tells us you want to compare `value` and `count` from different rows. So you should really show an example which will tickle that difference, i.e. don't keep `value` constant. Otherwise you're already getting answers which reference `value` from the wrong row, yet your test-data masks that issue. Can you please improve your question and data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a function to check if count is less than value. Then sort the data and use rank() to get the ranking per group (F_id and type). The function will check if rank is 1 or count is less than value.

```
def my_fnc(row):
    return row['rank'] > 1.0 and (row['count'] < row['value'])

data = pd.DataFrame({'F_id': [1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2]
                   , 'type': ['A','A','B', 'B','B','A','A','B','A',]
                   , 'count': [0,2,0,4,1,5,0,0,1]
                   , 'value': [8,8,2,2,2,8,3,9,3]} )
data['index_col'] = data.index 
data=data.sort_values(by=['F_id', 'type'])
data['rank'] = data.groupby(['F_id','type'])["index_col"].rank()
data['match'] = df.apply(lambda row: my_fnc(row), axis=1)
data.drop(columns=['index_col', 'rank'])

Result:


 F_id type count value  match
0   1   A   0   8   False
1   1   A   2   8   True
5   1   A   5   8   True
2   1   B   0   2   False
3   1   B   4   2   False
4   1   B   1   2   True
6   2   A   0   3   False
8   2   A   1   3   True
7   2   B   0   9   False
```

Comment: The question is problematic, apparently the OP wants to compare `value` and `count` from different rows, but their test-data has `value` column happening to be constant within every group, so buggy answers will silently pass. OP or someone needs to add better test-data.